# Using AngularFireStore with ionic 3 (angular 5 + rxjs5)

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, rxjs, angularfire2

I wanted to use angularfire2 to connect to firebase but I seem to be stuck in a dependency loop.

Ionic 3 officially supports up to angular 5, angularfire2 requires rxjs 6, angular 5 supports up to rxjs 5.

I can't upgrade to rxjs 6 since it isn't compatible with angular 5 and I can't upgrade to angular 6 since it isn't supported in ionic 3.

I was thinking of upgrading to ionic 4 since a lot of libraries break under my old angular version but I'm afraid ionic 4 beta will introduce even more bugs and my existing plugins my not be compatible.

Anyone got any idea what's the best course of action?

Comment: Ionic 4 has been officialy released a couple of days ago. [Announcing Ionic 4](https://blog.ionicframework.com/introducing-ionic-4-ionic-for-everyone/) They say on their blog `While there will be some work involved to migrate over, there’s never been a better time to do so` [Migrate to Ionic 4](https://blog.ionicframework.com/a-guide-for-migrating-to-ionic-4-0/). You likely have to / want to upgrade to Ionic 4 in the future anyway so why postpone and not do it now, if your current setup isn't working flawlessly anyway and you're looking into using the current version of angularfire2.

Comment: I have a project where I use Ionic 3 (3.9.2), Angular 5 (5.2.3) and rxjs 6.3.2 + rxjs compat lib. All works smooth. I also use @angular/fire": "5.0.0" (need to upgrade it ofc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[rxjs-compat](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md) should do the trick. Your concern about Ionic 4 is valid. I recently attempted the upgrade and found that:

1. The guides and tutorials grossly undersell the jump from v3 to v4, both in terms of the conceptual jump (e.g. Angular components -> web components) and the time involved (e.g. moving from SASS variables to CSS variables and other CSS tweaks that are necessary can be a lot of work)
2. Many plugins that I depend on are not yet compatible with v4 (in particular, Angular 7 and RxJS 6)

Still, the time to do the upgrade is now, just see it as a side project that might take a bit of time and keep your v3 app running well alongside it.

Comment: I would also like to add that if you upgrade to rxjs 6, you need to upgrade your typescript version to 3+